# import a file from different directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm using python 2.7. I have written a script, i need to import a function from some other file which is there in different folder.
my script is in the path

```
C:\python\xyz\xls.py
```

Path of File having function that i need to call is

```
C:\python\abc.py
```

i tried like this

```
from python.abc import *
```

but it is not working. Is there any other way to call the function or i need to move the files into same directory? Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can dynamically load a module from a file:

```
import imp
modl = imp.load_source('modulename', '/path/to/module.py')
```

The [imp module docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) will give you more details.

Comment: Thanks morphyn, answer is helpful

Comment: This worked, but is there a way to use classes from module without calling modl.class_name? Just class_name?

Comment: Well, you can do `ClassName = modl.ClassName` and then use it directly.

Answer (score 4):

You cat set the PYTHONPATH environment variable:

```
c:\> set PYTHONPATH=c:\python
```

And then, normally:

```
from abc import *
```

Alternatively, if you don't want or can't change the environment, you can change the path at runtime:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'c:\Python')
from abc import *
```

Comment: how can i use if i want to call 2 functions in 2 different files which are at different places? I tried like this

....import sys
....sys.path.append(r'c:\Python')
....from xyz.abc import*
....from qwe.fgh import*
but its not working. Please help

Comment: @Raghavendra: That's a different question so probably you should post it as such. Anyway, now it looks like you are trying to import packages, not plain modules, so a __init__.py file will be needed, I think. BTW, mixing your own modules into the python directory is probably not such a good idea... You should create a new directory for your projects.

Answer (score 2):

add `C:\python` in `sys.path`

also add a `__init__.py` file in `C:\python` so that python interpreter can import files from this folder

you should go through the [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Answer (score 1):

Take also a look at [import_file](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/import_file/1.11).
Some examples:

`>>>from import_file import import_file`

`>>>mylib = import_file('c:\mylib.py')`

`>>>another = import_file('relative_subdir/another.py')`

Comment: Thanks Tengis, but its showing error for the line "from import_file import import_file"

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.5 & above use this.

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("name", "path/to/file")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.MyClass()
```